# Xamarin build error 'cxmlns' is an undeclared prefix

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build my Xamarin.Forms project and running into an unexpected error "'cxmlns' is an undeclared prefix. Line 3, position 14". I've tried searching the web for a solution to this but not fining any. I've seen other similar problems and I tried solutions that worked for others, but nothing that worked in my case so far. Here is my MainPage.xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         cxmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DojoBoss"
         x:Class="DojoBoss.MainPage"
         BackgroundImage="background1">

</ContentPage>
```

I find it strange that I'm getting this error since this is all stock code that came with the blank app from Visual Studio (VS) aside from 1 line where I put in a background image. This was also working fine earlier today, I didn't make any changes but now it doesn't work. I've been disappointed with VS and Xamarin so far, seems very buggy and difficult to get started. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Build project
- Rebuild project
- Clean project
- Deselecting all projects from build (I have a main project + Android and Windows projects), applying changes, cleaning, building, re-selecting all projects to build multiple times in different orders.
- Deleting bin and obj folders
- Reopening VS multiple times
- Deleting .vs folder, including the .suo file
- Removing the line of code where error is thrown
- Checking the build order

VS is also giving me 4 other errors which may be related to the problem:

- Error    CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users...\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\DojoBoss.dll' could not be found
- The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
- Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'C:\Users...\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\DojoBoss.dll'
- The name ‘InitializeComponent’ does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what is this "cxmlns". Can we change this line

```
cxmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

to

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

Comment: O boy, that was simple! Thanks ZhichaoXiang. I think one of my kids pressed a key on my keyboard and added the c in there lol